# After using SSMS's Generate Scripts sqlcmd won't run it

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, backup

I tried backing up my database using SSMS Generate Scripts options. This produces a rather large file that SSMS won't run (memmory limit).

I tried then running this script using sqlcmd, but I get a syntax error.
I read that sqlcmd mode is different and I do not wish to manually remove the errors (there are potentially alot of them).

Is there a way to generate the script so it will obey the rules of sqlcmd or vice versa?

Comment: Why not edit your question and include the sqlcmd.exe arguments that you used as well as the error message, and maybe the line that it claims is bad syntax?

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing a backup with data, why don't you just right-click database - select tasks and backup and backup to a file?

Other than that, it would be hard to tell you what the error is without knowing what error you are getting.